# Creating floppy drive special devices under Quantal

Tags: 12.10, automount, udev, mate, floppy

First, I'd like for the various special devices for different floppy capacities (like `/dev/fd0u720` etc.) to be available. I tried to adapt some udev rules I found online. I tried this, which I saved as `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-floppy.rules`:

```
# change floppy device ownership and permissions
# default permissions are 640, which prevents group users from having write access

# first fix primary devices (/dev/fd0, /dev/fd1, etc.)
# also change group ownership from disk to floppy
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="fd[0-9]*", GROUP="floppy", MODE="0660"

# next recreate secondary devices (/dev/fd0u720, /dev/fd0u1440, etc.)
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="fd[0-9]*", ACTION=="add", RUN+="create_floppy_devices -c -t $attr{cmos} -m %M -M 0660 -G floppy $root/%k"
```

But to no avail. It seems the `create_floppy_devices` script isn't provided with 12.10. How do I obtain it?

Second: I'm using MATE, and whenever I log in I get a message box saying it tried to mount the drive but failed. How do I disable this?

Third (which is probably related to the second): Whenever there's a disk in the drive, the motor won't stop spinning. If I do a `mdir` of it, after it returns, the motor stops, and then starts again. I suspect there's some process in MATE doing this.

**UPDATE:** For CentOS 6 (who *does* have a `create_floppy_devices` program) the following rules file worked. Saved as `/etc/udev/rules.d/98-floppy.rules`:

```
# change floppy device ownership and permissions
# default permissions are 640, which prevents group users from having write access

# first fix primary devices (/dev/fd0, /dev/fd1, etc.)
# also change group ownership from disk to floppy
KERNEL=="fd[0-9]*", GROUP="floppy", MODE="0660"

# next recreate secondary devices (/dev/fd0u720, /dev/fd0u1440, etc.)
# drive A: is type 4 (1.44MB) - add other lines for other drives
KERNEL=="fd0*", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/lib/udev/create_floppy_devices -c -t 4 -m %M -M 0660 -G floppy $root/%k"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really seems that `create_floppy_devices` is not available in Ubuntu. To make this work you can try two things:

- Download the source code and try to compile it manually. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/braindamaged/udev/src/f612629a7d0d/src/floppy/create_floppy_devices.c) is the code of that utility (it is a fork of udev, but you can search in the internet for the original);
- `fdutils` package provide a command called `MAKEFLOPPIES` that seem similar to create_floppy_devices. You can check if it suits your needs and adapt that script to use it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! That took care of device creation. Now all that's left is the annoying automount/spinning motor thing MATE does.

Comment: To solve those i suggest you to create separate questions to each one, because they don't seem very related with your first problem, and are more likely to receive attention.